# How to group by continuous days in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table where I am storing some sequential data that indicate occurrences of some event given day.

```
id     from_id        to_id   date
1      2              1       2014-08-01
2      2              1       2014-08-02

3      2              1       2014-08-04
4      2              1       2014-08-05
6      2              1       2014-08-06
```

Sometimes event hasn't got place. Then I would like to get min and max from every uninterrupted sequences of records by data. **According to example data it should return**

```
from_id        to_id   min            max
2              1       2014-08-01     2014-08-02
2              1       2014-08-04     2014-08-06
```

If I would do simple group by with min and max

```
Select from_id, to_id, min(date), max(date) from events group by from_id, to_id
```

it would return

```
from_id        to_id   min            max
2              1       2014-08-01     2014-08-06
```

How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: What version of Mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT from_id,to_id,
  CONCAT_WS(' - ',
    MIN(dt),
    CASE WHEN MAX(dt)>MIN(dt) THEN MAX(dt) END
  ) As intervals
FROM (
  SELECT from_id,to_id,
    CASE WHEN dt=@last_ci+INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @last_ci := dt As dt
  FROM
    t, (SELECT @n:=0) r
  ORDER BY
    dt
) s
GROUP BY
  g
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e61c/1)

Comment: it fails when used with ORM tool like ebean, didn't find escape char for :=

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810311/ebean-orm-escape-character-in-sqlquery

Comment: You should add from_id,to_id to GROUP BY. If you add more from_id, to_id pairs you will get non-deterministic answers

Answer (score 0):

Rough sketch for a standard SQL92 solution, if you only intend to use MySQL @Mihai solution using variables will probably be a lot more efficient:

```
SELECT lb.from_id, lb.to_id, MAX(lb.dt) as from_date, ub.dt as to_date 
FROM (
    -- find start
    SELECT from_id, to_id, dt 
    FROM t t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM t t2 WHERE T2.dt = DATE_SUB(t1.dt,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    )
) as lb
JOIN (
    -- find end
    SELECT FROM_ID, to_ID, dt FROM t t3
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM t t4 
        WHERE t4.dt = DATE_add(t3.dt,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    )
) as Ub
    -- pair start with end
    ON lb.dt < ub.DT
   AND lb.from_id = ub.from_id
   AND lb.to_id = ub.to_id
GROUP BY lb.from_id, lb.to_id, ub.dt
```

;

If you are using a newer version of MySQL, it is much more efficient to use window functions. Search for island and gaps for examples